# How to make a WAMP server secure. Is it possible?

Tags: security, wamp, self-hosting

Yesterday I setup a localhost on my network, and now am working on making it a public website. I read that self-hosting a website with WAMP can be very insecure, and poses high security risks. Is this true? How would I make my WAMP server secure? I currently have Windows Vista (most recent service pack), Kaspersky Pure 3.0, and WAMP 2.2.
 If you could please post a solution, or tips on keeping my self-hosted website secure, it would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Please read the first sentence of the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and ask yourself "How is this question relevant to the topic of this site?"...

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour Please read the third bullet: `software tools commonly used by programmers`, I believe that this question not only will help me, but will help many other people in the future!

Comment: Have you read [the entire page](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for clarification? "Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming or software development within the scope defined in the FAQ." There are other non-programming sites in the stackexchange network, which is where this belongs...

Comment: I'm sure that if a moderator feels the need to migrate this question, then they will. Thank you for your concerns!

Comment: WAMP is not meant for production IMO and if you're hosting it from home it will be terrible slow. As for security concerns, WAMP has error reporting on by default, mysql has no password and the user "root" should be changed. phpmyadmin and sqlbuddy is accessible everywhere, you could limit it to a specific IP. This is as far I can tell for the moment.